# Terraform Azure Service Principal Client Secret expiration

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is it really not possible to set the expiration date for a client secret?

I tried looking at the docs (see below), and I can't find anything other than the output of the expiration Terraform which is two years.

I can't even view the secret on Azure AD since it doesn't show up in the Client Secrets area (though this might be due to some sort of replication/eventual consistency lag).

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal_password

Comment: Hello @ton.yeung,please use this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password instead of service principal password and you can also declare expiry date here as `end date relative = 2h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service Principal Password** cannot be seen in the Portal, you can only find the value of it from the Terraform state. As **Service Principal** is referred to `Enterprise Application` , we can use the secret with the client id but it won't be visible in portal as `Enterprise application` doesn't have a  `certificates and secrets blade`.

So, in order to make it visible in portal you have to use **Application Password** so that it can be seen in the `certificates and secrets blade` of the **App Registration**.

Also in the Application Password you can use `relative end date` in hours corresponding to the time you want the secret to expire.

**You can use something like below:**

```
provider "azuread" {}

data "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name = "aksspansuman"
}
resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  display_name = "Test"
  application_object_id = data.azuread_application.example.object_id
  end_date_relative = "24h"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

```
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "example" {
  service_principal_id = data.azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
  end_date = "2021-11-18T01:02:03Z"
}
```

If We try using `end_date` in SP password it gives the below error.

[image]

Comment: Hi, while this tells me why it doesn't show up, it doesn't solve the long password TTL. I'm trying to use the SP for terraform, so I'd like to make the TTL shorter. Using the app registration client secret is not an option. Is there no way to set the expiration date of the SP password?

Comment: Unfortunately, no @ton.yeung, application password can also be used in terraform as a client secret. if you do it from portal its pretty same for SP and Application but terraform and IAC tools use application password and SP password separately . but they have the same purpose.

Comment: let me check bit more and get back here

Comment: @ton.yeung , please find the update in answer . as expiry date is not possible in SP password and  As I have already mentioned you can use  Client_id as app registration and service principal have same clientid and Client Secret  from application password . It will work for authentication purpose or any other purpose in azure. I have used the same way